# U.S. Census Data, Block Level, Where to Find It

Tags: census, data

Does the Census Bureau still release block level data, say for 2014? If so, has anybody been able to successfully procure it, and how?

I spent a large portion of yesterday exploring the FactFinder website and others looking for Block Level data. I am looking for general demographic data, general housing data, and even the blocks themselves for a community fire study I am working on. I can adjust the variables based on what data is available.

I understand that due to reporting and privacy that certain areas are available in different scales. I am looking for block level data for San Jose, CA and Santa Clara County, CA (which in the past been made available by block) . I am only able to find a few links to 2010 data at that level but hoping to find newer data. I don't even see the block level in the drop down selections (I have played with numerous data sets to see if they populate the block selection).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Bureau does not have block data from 2014 only from the 2010 Census. The 2014 data is based on the American Community Survey which is based on a sample of the population instead of all the population like the 2010 Census.

Comment: thank you for the information. I did some deeper searching and finally found documentation explaining the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Block GROUPS are the smallest level of geography the census summarizes American Community Survey data. <-- This primarily answers the question. So no you cannot get "Block" data you can get *Block Group* data. Block Groups have the highest precision geographically but the highest margin of error. So you can download all the socioeconomic data for Block Groups, Tracts, Zip Codes, and Counties. ACS is 5 year summary of sample population. The 2010 - 2014 data set is there. 2015 is most recent right now. I was released earlier this month (December 2016).